# How to set algorithm to make the program do the increment of 2 numbers

Tags: javascript

what algorithm to increase the values of an object between 1 and 3, for example:
run number 1 value should be 0.001; run number 2,value should be 0.003; run number 3,value should be 0.01; run number 4,value should be 0.03; run number 5,value should be 0.1; run number 6,value should be 0.3... and so on.
I cannot think of algorithm for my program that would generate these value. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I think this question mentions a lot of needless information. Can you remove any unnecessary information, and focus entirely on the sequence of numbers you wish to generate?

Answer (score 1):

I would just assume that:

> initial value would be 0.001
> for sequence with even index, the next value will be multiplied by 3
> for sequence with odd index, the next value will be divided by 3 and multiplied by 10

here is working code

```
// it will generate array with n values;
function weirdIncrement(n){
  let arr = [];
  let a = 0.001;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // when i is even, the next a will be divided by 3 and multiplied by 10
    // else, the next a will just be multiplied by 3
    if(i%2){
      arr.push(a);
      a = a/3*10
    }
    else{
      arr.push(a);
      a = a*3
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you wish to generate a sequence like:

```
0.001
0.003
0.01
0.03
0.1
0.3
1
3
10
30
100
300
...
```

A generator can implement this very directly:

```js
let customSequence = function*(vals, mult=10, len=0) {
  for (let i = 0; !len || i < len; i++)
    for (let val of vals)
      yield Math.pow(mult, i) * val;
}

console.log([ ...customSequence([ 0.001, 0.003 ], 10, 20) ]);
```

This was a matter of defining the correct generator, and then supplying it with the right initial arguments.